# Android drag and drop API: Can I force dragging in only one direction?

Tags: android, drag

I'm using the Android drag API (startDrag) on the view, but I need to make the view only draggable in one direction (i.e. bottom only). Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

you could try my solution, and only change the needed margins - left&right for horizontal dragging, or top&bottom for vertical dragging:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18806475/878126