# Dragable button just like unlock button in Android default emulator

Tags: android, button, android-emulator, unlock

I need a drag able button just like unlock button in Android default  emulator (similar to image below). Can any one help me how to implement it? I need layout or code for it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the button draggable `attach a listener` to the Object such as `OnTouchListener, OnLongClickListener` . When the user drags the data a image is displayed and it is called as Drag Shadow. It is initialized using the constructor View.DragShadowBuilder. The dragging is started using `startDrag()` method which has four parameters.

To create a Drop view we must attach `OnDragListener` to the view where the data is to be dropped. Various actions which execute during the process are.

Sample code:

```
  myOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
             if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                 oldXvalue = me.getX();
                 oldYvalue = me.getY();
                 Log.i(myTag, "Action Down " + oldXvalue + "," + oldYvalue);
             }else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE  ){
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),(int)(me.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2)), (int)(me.getRawY() - (v.getHeight())));
                v.setLayoutParams(params);
             }
             return true;
         }
     };
```

For more details, please refer [here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/03/android-drag-and-drop-example.html).

Comment: tanks, i need a widget for this functionality, does any widget exist for it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892853/how-to-use-correct-dragging-of-a-view-on-android/18806475#18806475