# Drag And Drop a Button to a specific position in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, drag-and-drop, imageview

I am developing an app, which needs a button to be dragged and dropped to a particular place ie., I have a button named "btn" at a specific position (Eg.default position (0,0) ), i need to drag that button and drop it at a particular coordinate (Eg. button should be dragged and dropped at (250,250) ).  If the button is dragged and dropped somewhere else other than that coordinate, it should return back to its origin.
             Please help me with a piece of code for this task as soon as possible.

Comment: What is your code so far? You can also look at this question in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037799/how-to-make-drag-drop-button-in-android which about the same

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial [Moving Android views](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/). 
Then you should be good to go.