# Draggable EditText by User

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to make an edit text within my UI that a user can physically drag from one part of teh screen to another. It's within a FrameLayout right now.

I've tried looking around, but not seen much help for moving the box as a whole rather than just moving data from one view to another.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
     myOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
         if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
             oldXvalue = me.getX();
             oldYvalue = me.getY();
             Log.i(myTag, "Action Down " + oldXvalue + "," + oldYvalue);
         }else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE  ){
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),(int)(me.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2)), (int)(me.getRawY() - (v.getHeight())));
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
         }
         return true;
     }
 };
```

See: [How to make Drag & Drop Button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037799/how-to-make-drag-drop-button-in-android)