# Comparing text of two button using drag & drop

Tags: android

I have two type of button in my application,one in name of city and other one is center of city.I decided to drag one of them and put on another, 
So when the button is over the other one, I check the text of two button programmatically.
Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your button text with :

```
YourBtn.getText().toString();
```

and you can compare them by :

```
if(YourBtn.getText().toString().equal(SecondButton.getText.toString()))
{
  //do your work
}
```

Edit : [How To Make Drag&Drop Button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037799/how-to-make-drag-drop-button-in-android/12356459#12356459)

Comment: How could I understand the button is exactly over another button?

Comment: see,I want to drag button and put on the other button then I compare them.

Comment: plz look at the edited answer,according to that link i think you can check the x and y position of your view on that MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE event.

Comment: I mean that in OnTouchListener of your button you can check which position exactly your dragged button is, so you can check the dragged Button's x and y position and compare it with your first and static button.

Comment: @Arash I use AbsoluteLayout, So I couldn't use like this.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and not recommended anymore.

Comment: So What should I do now?

Comment: I think Attched link will help you , but i don't have any clue about your layout or how you can implement your position or overlapping check.it's a bit complex so break your questions to part then implement it part by part to achieve your goal then in specific problems ask specific question.

Comment: Ok,Could I speak persian with you?

Comment: Please give me your email.

Comment: I don't know how email you. :(

Comment: Arashgolmohammadi@gmail.com