# Dynamically reposition view in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to reposition a view (which contains a canvas element) dynamically. The idea is to have the user touch the box and be able to drag it around the screen. I intend to grab the touch motion_events in order to reposition the block where the user is dragging. This is the code I currently have which I thought would work but hasn't produced any success so far.

```
int[] coords = getLastLocations();

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

View mainv = findViewById(R.id.mainRelativeLayout);
BoxView bvr = (BoxView) findViewById(R.id.BoxViewRed);
BoxView bvb = (BoxView) findViewById(R.id.BoxViewBlue);
bvr.setColor(255, 0, 0);
bvr.layout(coords[0], coords[1], 60, 60);
bvb.setColor(0, 0, 255);
bvb.layout(coords[2], coords[3], 60, 60);

mainv.invalidate();
```

Any tips on how to get this code to work or another method would be perfect.

P.S. Targeting ICS+ (API 14-19)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037799/how-to-make-drag-drop-button-in-android

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: @Daniel, this seems like a good method, I'll try it out when I have time and update the post if it works.

Comment: ok, glad you will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

you can dynamically position a view using setX and setY on the View. For example, the fixed code looks like this:

```
    int[] coords = getLastLocations();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View mainv = findViewById(R.id.mainRelativeLayout);
    BoxView bvr = (BoxView) findViewById(R.id.BoxViewRed);
    BoxView bvb = (BoxView) findViewById(R.id.BoxViewBlue);

    bvr.setColor(255, 0, 0);
    bvr.setX(coords[0]);
    bvr.setY(coords[1]);
    bvb.setColor(0, 0, 255);
    bvb.setX(coords[2]);
    bvb.setY(coords[3]);
```

Keep in mind this will position elements in pixel value, you may have to do unit conversion if you use DIPs for your views etc. to get everything to look right.