# Draggable Button Creates A "Ghost Button"

Tags: android

When I first launch the app, the button appears on (0,0). After dragging it, a "ghost button" appears and starts from (0,0). After moving it again, there are two translucent buttons. One starts where I dragged it, and one starts at (0,0). The other problem is that the button dragged sometimes appears where the "ghost button" is. Here is the code for moving the button:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
        bounds = new RectF(getX(), getY(), getX()+getRight(), getY()+getBottom());
        if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        }else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            if(bounds.contains(getX(), getY())) {
                this.setX(me.getX());
                this.setY(me.getY());
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is 'this' in the context of your code? Can you post more code?

Comment: Maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037799/how-to-make-drag-drop-button-in-android

Comment: 'this' in the contex of my code is the custom button class.